# What we can add to make Query Run faster in Oracle ? Below is Oracle Query slowness

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(TRN.ACCRUALPTS), 0) AS ACCRUALPTS
  FROM TrsanctionTable REQ INNER JOIN 
       TRSANCTIONTABLEREQ TRN ON TRN.TRNREQID = REQ.TRNREQID INNER JOIN 
       CARDTABLE CARD ON CARD.CARDID = TRN.CARDID
 WHERE TRN.CUSTOMERID = 4082
   AND TRN.STATUSCODE = '2220'
   AND REQ.STATUSCODE = '00'
   AND TRN.BATCHID IS NULL;
```

Above Query which is taking much time to execute, Could you suggest me that how I can rewrite or change this query to run faster. My team suggest to Add composite index on this query.

Is their anything else that can work to reduce the cost of this QUERY

**COST OF THIS QUERY IS 102K**

> NOTE: Indexing Already Apply on Single columns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ziyad. Can you please post whole explain plan with object names and access methods?

Comment: What is the purpose of including the table CARDTABLE when it is not being used anywhere?

Comment: The join on CARDTABLE looks unneeded. unless you need it to exclude records with an invalid TRN.CARDID?

Comment: Please, execute your query with `/*+GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS*/` hint and paste a textual output from `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE ALLSTATS LAST'))` which should be executed just after your query.

Comment: @NickW there is a join on CARDTABLE the card which done transaction is valid one or not

Comment: @astentx ok paste the same

Comment: The information you've included shows the execution only takes 5s - this does not seem to be particularly slow. How fast do you want it to run?

Comment: @NickW Its take almost 5 to 4min to run this query

Comment: In which case you definitely need to do what @astentx has suggested so that you can provide enough information for anyone to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(TRN.ACCRUALPTS), 0) AS ACCRUALPTS
FROM TrsanctionTable REQ INNER JOIN 
     TRSANCTIONTABLEREQ TRN 
     ON TRN.TRNREQID = REQ.TRNREQID INNER JOIN 
     CARDTABLE CARD
     ON CARD.CARDID = TRN.CARDID
 WHERE TRN.CUSTOMERID = 4082 AND
       TRN.STATUSCODE = '2220' AND
       REQ.STATUSCODE = '00' AND
       TRN.BATCHID IS NULL;
```

Multi-column indexes will definitely help.  It is not 100% clear what the best approach is without knowing the sizes of the tables and how selecting the filters are.  But I am guessing this would help a lot:

- `TRSANCTIONTABLEREQ(CUSTOMERID, STATUSCODE, BATCHID, STATUSCODE, ACCRUALPTS)`
- `TrsanctionTable(TRNREQID, STATUSCODE, CARDID)`
- `CARDTABLE(CARDID)`

Comment: Yes i have apply Multi-column indexes. But not much different in Query Running Time